# SharePoint Apps vs Features

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I can't really get the difference between SharePoint apps and features. When should I create my solution into an app and when in a feature ?

I know that the apps were recently introduced in the 2013 version of SharePoint, but what makes it different from a sharepoint feature ?

Comment: The question here at StackOverflow is preferred to be such that can be answered, not discussed - http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refer this MSDN article. That will explain everything what you are questioning right now.

[Deciding between apps for SharePoint and SharePoint solutions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn268593(v=office.15).aspx)

Also consider the comment of Taras. :)